# Port Unification in Wildfly-8.2.1

Tags: java, https, wildfly-8, ear

I have an EAR application having structure like,

abc.ear

- def.war
- def1.war
- ghi.jar

The application is running fine on a Wildfly server separately as,

1. HTTP: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/
2. HTTPS: https://localhost:8443/HelloWorld/

I want to redirect all the HTTP (Port 8080) requests to the HTTPS (Port 8443).
Any help is heartily appreciated.

Comment: have you checked this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: Yes, but that link only helps in securing the web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a webapp packaged in an EAR file. So you could add this in webapp web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>everything</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Thus if a user access your application from its browser using http://..., it will be "redirected" to https://...

Note: You have also to configure SSL in Wildfly security-realms but I assume you already did it